# How to get the elementwise day of the year from an numpy datetime array?

Tags: python-2.7

Do you have an idea, how I can get the elementwise day of the year from an numpy datetime array?
With my code I can only receive the day of the year for one element in the array.How can I get the day of the year for each element in the array?
Here is my code (including your code):

```
#import modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime 
from datetime import datetime

#date values in an numpy array as int
data_int = np.array([[20131001, 20131001, 20131001],
                    [20131002, 20131002, 20131002],
                    [20131002, 20131002, 20131002]])
#transform the data_int array in a datetime list
data_list = [pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(x), format="%Y%m%d") for x in   data_int]
#transform the datetime list back to an datetime array with dtype='datetime64[ns]')
data = np.asarray(data_list, dtype='datetime64', order=None)
#convert dtype='datetime64[ns]' into a datetime.date object 
data_date = data.astype('M8[D]').astype('O')
#get the day of the year from the the data_date array.
day_of_year = data_date[0,1].timetuple().tm_yday
#274
```

It would be great if you or someone else has an good idea for me!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#date values in an numpy array as int
data_int = np.array([[20131001, 20131001, 20131001],
                    [20131002, 20131002, 20131002],
                    [20131002, 20131002, 20131002]])
#transform the data_int array in a datetime list
data_list = [pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(x), format="%Y%m%d") for x in data_int]
doy = pd.DataFrame([x.apply(lambda x: x.timetuple().tm_yday) for x in data_list]).values
print(doy)
```

Output:

```
[[274 274 274]
 [275 275 275]
 [275 275 275]]
```

Comment: Hi Ophir Carmi, thx very much for your help. Now it is really easy to calculate the day of the year! But I have one more question. I need to start the calculation at the 1. of October. Therefore I modified your code a little bit and it works. But there is one defect - the output array has a different shape (instead (3,3)shape I got a (3,1)shape. What is wrong? It must have something to do with iteration...Would be great if you have an idea to fix this problem. Greetings,

Answer (score 0):

Here is my modified code, which starts the day of the year caluculation at the
1. October. Unfortunately with this code I get a wrong numpy array shape.
Instead of a shape with (3,3) I get a shape with (3.1). Why??? 
I'm very happy for any good ideas to solve this problem.

```
#import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#test numpy array
data_int = np.array([[0., 20131001., 20131001.],
                     [20131002., 20131002., 20131002.],
                     [20131002., 20131002., 20140930.]])
#replace zero values with nan in the data_int numpy array
data_int[data_int==0]=['nan']
#transform the data_int array in a datetime list
data_list = [pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(x), format="%Y%m%d") for x in data_int]
#create a datetime start date
start_date = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series('20131001'), format="%Y%m%d")
#caluculate the day of year. Unfortunately with this function
#I got an wrong numpy array shape with (3,1) instead of (3.3).
doy = pd.DataFrame([x.apply(lambda x: x - start_date) for x in data_list]).values
#print doy. Thats how my result looks right now. 

#array([[       0
#0    NaT
#1 0 days
#2 0 days],
#       [       0
#0 1 days
#1 1 days
#2 1 days],
#       [         0
#0   1 days
#1   1 days
#2 364 days]], dtype=object)

#and that's how my endresult should look like:
data_out = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 1],
                     [1, 1, 1]])
```